# Bivariate Normal Distribution and sub vector

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Let $$(X,Y)\sim N(\mu^\rightarrow ,\Sigma)$$
we cannot assume anything about the dependancy between X and Y.
Can we assume the following? $$X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma ^2_x)~,~Y\sim N(\mu_y, \sigma^2_y)$$note:(X,Y) is not necessarily standard bivariate normal distributed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! They are both *marginally* normally distributed, just, as you say, you do not know the relation between the two.

The density funciton of $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ can be found at [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function). The specific case where you have a vector of length $2$, ie your $(X,Y)$, rather than a general $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ is given [its own subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case). If you take this density function, say $f(x,y)$, and integrate over all $Y = y$, then you get the density function of the marginal distribution for $X$: $f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) dy$.

If you do this integral yourself, you'll find that $f_X(x)$ is precisely the density function of a $N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ distribution! The same argument holds, analogously, for $f_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) dx$.

So, the diagonal terms in $\Sigma$ describe the variance of the marginals of $X$ and $Y$ and the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is described by the off-diagonal terms.

You can also prove this by writing $(X,Y)$ as a matrix times a vector of independent standard normals, plus a mean shift. See [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector) for details of this representation.

Comment: I tried to integrate the joint density function over Y (the bounds that i uesd were -inf<y<inf) and actually i don't know how to solve this integral so i'ill be happy to see the whole solution.

Comment: I gave two methods for solving this. But people aren't here to just give you an answer. You'll need to add more details to the question to show what you tried. For the integral, just take pdf $f(x,y)$ and 'complete the square' in the numerator wrt $y$---eg, $2x^2 + 4xy + y^2 = (y - 2x)^2 - 2x^2$---then you just get the usual Gaussian integral, but with $y$ translated---by $2x$ in the example I just gave

Comment: You can also just search for "marginal pdf of multivariate gaussian integral" and terms like that. The answer should be fairly easily findable and you might well learn something on your way to finding it!